# How to write one function that handles multiple classes actions

Tags: php, jquery

I have created multiple lines with an Arrow button on the left,and a heading on the right of it.The arrow itself is a span with a background image that represents two states:open,close(triangle that is rotated 45deg).
Beneath it,I hide the paragraph.
On an Arrow click,the background position of span background(arrow-triangle) changes so it looks like the list unfolds.And paragraph becomes visible.
To handle multiple lines of the same schema (span(arrow),heading,hidden paragraph) I dynamically define 
the class,heading and paragraph using php:

```
 <?php function faq($num,$quest,$answer){
echo "<div class='freqlist'>
            <span class='arrowlist$num'></span>
            <h2>$quest</h2>
            <p class='hideans hideans$num'>$answer</p>
        </div>"
  ?>
```

then edit html to add text lines to fold-unfold list:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <?php faq('1','Вопросы','Ответы')?>
        <?php faq('2','Приветы','Котлеты')?>
        <?php faq('3','От Боси','Лапососи')?>
        <?php faq('4','К Полинке','И Владосе')?>
        <?php faq('5','С приветом','Мы на радость')?>
        <?php faq('6','Бока','Отлежав')?>
        <?php faq('7','Мы тут кодим','Не спавши')?>
        <?php faq('8','Эту повесть','Напесавши')?>
    </div>
</section>
```

then jquery to make the heading unfold onclick,show paragraph and make an arrow rotate; and reverse on click again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*block of show/hide pars*/
    $ind=0;
    $('.arrowlist1').click(function(){if($ind==0){showlist1()}else{hidelist1()}});      
    function showlist1(){
        $('.arrowlist1').css('background-position', '-9px -65px');$ind=1;
        $('.hideans1').show('400');
    }
    function hidelist1(){
        $('.arrowlist1').css('background-position', '-4px -8px');$ind=0;
        $('.hideans1').hide('400')
    }     


     $('.arrowlist2').click(function(){if($ind==0){showlist2()}else{hidelist2()}});     
    function showlist2(){
        $('.arrowlist2').css('background-position', '-9px -65px');$ind=1;
        $('.hideans2').show('400');
    }
    function hidelist2(){
        $('.arrowlist2').css('background-position', '-4px -8px');$ind=0;
        $('.hideans2').hide('400')
    }
```

.etc.
As you can see I have to write tons of the same code to make the same action to each of text line.
How can I write one function to handle each of the list lines automatically?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make `showList()` and `hideList()` accept a number and use that to determine which `.arrowlist<n>` and `.hideans<n>` to show/hide:

```
function showlist(n){
    $('.arrowlist' + n).css('background-position', '-9px -65px');
    $('.hideans' + n).show('400');
}
function hidelist(n){
    $('.arrowlist' + n).css('background-position', '-4px -8px');
    $('.hideans' + n).hide('400')
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$('.arrowlist1').click(function(){toggleList(1)});
```

And the `toggleList()` function:

```
function toggleList(n) {
    if ( $('.hideans' + n).is(":visible") ) {
        hideList(n)
    } else {
        showList(n)
    } 
}
```